# PHPExcel add multiple sheets for each result PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel, spreadsheet

I am trying to add more sheets into a single excel spreadsheet.

What my code below is doing right now is outputting all my data from my php mysql database into worksheet1, and also creating 29 new separate blank worksheets with nothing in them.

What I want to do is to put each result (each row) into a single worksheet.

Any help appreciated!

Cheers,

```
/** Create a new PHPExcel object 1.0 */
   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Data');
   }  

/** Loop through the result set 1.0 */
    $rowNumber = 1; //start in cell 1

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
       $col = 'A'; // start at column A
       foreach($row as $cell) {

       $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
         $col++;
       }
       $rowNumber++;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhpExcel create sheet for each result row PHP MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162617/phpexcel-create-sheet-for-each-result-row-php-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/** Create a new PHPExcel object 1.0 */
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Data');

/** Loop through the result set */
$rowNumber = 1; //start in row 1

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $newsheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
    $col = 'A'; // start at column A
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        $newsheet->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
        $col++;
    }
    $rowNumber++;
}
```

Comment: THanks for your help Mark,
THis is what it outputs now:

As there is 2 entries inside my database, there should only be 2 workbooks in the outputted excel file. However there is 3. The first workbook is empty. the first entry is in workbook 2. the second entry is in workbook 3.

Comment: `$objPHPExcel->removeSheetByIndex(0);` before your `while` loop